# Why doesn't integration by parts work in this case?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve

$\int \sin(x)\cos(t-x)dx$

without using any trigonometric identities, but when I use integration by parts (I'm using the tabular method, differentiating $\cos(t-x)$ and integrating $\sin(x)$), I end up with:

$\int \sin(x)\cos(t-x)dx = -\cos(t-x)\cos(x)+\sin(t-x)\sin(x) + \int \sin(x)\cos(t-x)dx + C$

$0 = \sin(t-x)\sin(x) - \cos(t-x)\cos(x) +C$

Am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to evaluate this integral using only integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong, but that will not work.

$$\begin{align}\int\sin(x)\cos(t-x)\,\mathrm d x &= -\int\cos(t-x)\,\mathrm d\cos(x)\\&= - \cos(x)\cos(t-x)+\int\cos(x)\,\mathrm d\cos(t-x)\\&= - \cos(x)\cos(t-x)+\int\cos(x)\sin(t-x)\,\mathrm d x\\&= - \cos(x)\cos(t-x)+\int\sin(t-x)\,\mathrm d \sin(x)\\&= - \cos(x)\cos(t-x)+\sin(x)\sin(t-x)-\int\sin(x)\,\mathrm d \sin(t-x)\\&= - \cos(x)\cos(t-x)+\sin(x)\sin(t-x)+\int\sin(x)\cos(t-x)\,\mathrm d x
\end{align}$$

Notice the cos(sum) formula will give you:
$$\begin{align}\cos(A)\cos(B)-\sin(A)\sin(B) &=\cos(A+B)\\[2ex]
\therefore\quad\cos(t-x)\cos(x)-\sin(t-x)\sin(x)&=\cos(t)\end{align}$$

Congradulations!  You have proven that $\cos(t)$ is a constant.  Uh, so yeah... this is a dead end.

---

I suggest starting with $\cos(t-x)=\cos(t)\cos(x)+\sin(t)\sin(x)$ and see how that progresses.